# How to use Select2 jQuery plug-in in a stand-alone HTML page?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I have used select2 jQuery plug-in inside my Rails app before, that's fine. But, I need to use it inside a stand-alone HTML page. I am using jQuery source from google using this :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

But, in order to use select2 jQuery plug-in inside the HTML page, I need to specify the src from an online link. I could not find such link anywhere. (May be I am dumb). SO, for a work around I put the select2 folder in my dropbox folder and using something like this to use select2 plug-in :

```
<script src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kizh5ant6aomum/select2.js?dl=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8c0pw5r7t791gh/select2.css?dl=1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

which does not seem to be a good solution to me. Also, some of the images are not working properly and in my javascript console I can see some errors like this :

```
GET https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/r8c0pw5r7t791gh/select2.png 403 (FORBIDDEN) Sample%20HTML%20File.html:55
GET https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/r8c0pw5r7t791gh/select2-spinner.gif 403 (FORBIDDEN) jquery.min.js:4
GET https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/r8c0pw5r7t791gh/select2.png 403 (FORBIDDEN) jquery.min.js:4
```

SO, what I should I do get a clean solution for my problem ? and what would be the best way of using select2 jQuery plug-in inside a single stand alone HTML page ? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you put them with your HTML?

Comment: You mean all the css I should put them inside the html page? and also, how to put the images ? I have a requirement that I can not keep the files in my server :(

Comment: Have you tried actually looking in the official github site? I found this right away: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-master/select2.js & http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.css

Comment: No, in the same directory where the HTML page resides.

Comment: I can't keep them in the directory, thats the requiremnt :(

Comment: @darkajax Is it fine / legal to hotlink from there? Also, what if that domain is not accessible?

Comment: THANKS EVERY ONE FOR 3 NEGATIVE VOTES WITHIN A MINUTE. THAT WAS AWESOME GUYS. RATHER THAN POINTING OUT THE RIGHT THING TO THE PERSON WHO DID NOT REALLY KNOW THE ACTUAL THING AND AFTER LOTS OF TRIAL HE POSTED THE QUESTION ! BUT YOU GUYS ARE TOO AWESOME TO PUT HIM OFF LIKE THIS ! THANKS AGAIN TO ALL OF YOU. GOD BLESS YOU GUYS.

Comment: @KeenLearner You should not blame people this way, as it clearly shows that you haven't put in any effort of getting a right way.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I am not blaming anyone. Please don't get me wrong. And truly, I have tried for atleast 3 hours. But, did not work for me for some reason. Even I tried a link from github too. But did not work at that time. Would you believe that? Thanks anyways for your time and help.

Comment: @KeenLearner Anyways, all the best! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the files in the official github site: [**JS File**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-master/select2.js) & [**CSS File**](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.css).

In cases like this you can use Chrome's Developer tools of Firefox's Firebug on the examples/demo pages to find the actual files used and avoid issues...

Comment: Many Thanks for the help. Sometimes it happens !

Comment: Hi, I still can't get the link that you found and provided (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-master/select2.js) if I go to their official github page (https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2). I could see (https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js) which I tried before but did not work. Your link (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-master/select2.js) is working great for me. But,  unfortunately I can't see the link if I go to their website :( Could you please point out where it is exactly in the website ? Thanks in advance.@darkajax

Comment: It's on the main github project page, if you go directly to https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js you'll see it, and it actually lists https://raw.github.com/ivaynberg/select2/master/select2.js as the raw code, so that could be a better source

Comment: Yes, I saw these 2 links in main github page. But could you please tell me where did you get this EXACT (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-master/select2.js) link ? @darkajax

Comment: Mmm, sorry I got confused. I actually found http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-3.3.2/select2.js and the css equivalent on the demos on http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ AND tried changing the `3.3.2` with `master`